# VAO not rendering colors OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, vao

I was hoping to get some help on an OpenGL question concerning the creation and rendering of VAOs. The goal here is simply to take this:

```
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
glColor4f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
glVertex3f(-0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f);
glVertex3f(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f);
glVertex3f(0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f);
glVertex3f(-0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f);
glVertex3f(0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f);
glVertex3f(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f);
glEnd();
```

which renders a red square in the middle of the window, and turn it into a VAO with vertices, colors, and indices. Now, this is what I have so far as far as creating the VAO (sorry if this is a bit long for the code):

```
//initialize all data
verts_amt = 6;

Vertex* verts = (Vertex*)malloc(sizeof(Vertex) * verts_amt);
int* indices = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * verts_amt);

verts[0] = createVertex(-0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
verts[1] = createVertex(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
verts[2] = createVertex(0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
verts[3] = createVertex(-0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
verts[4] = createVertex(0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
verts[5] = createVertex(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

int i;
for(i = 0; i < 6; i ++)
    indices[i] = i;

unsigned int vbo, ibo;
//create, bind, set data, and then unbind for the vbo and ibo
glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, verts_amt * sizeof(Vertex), verts, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

glGenBuffers(1, &ibo);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, verts_amt * sizeof(int), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

//create vao, bind vao, bind and set data for vbo, bind ibo, then unbind vao
glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
glBindVertexArray(vao);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);

glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), NULL);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (void*)offsetof(Vertex, r));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo);
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

in case you are wondering, `Vertex` is just a struct made up of seven floats in the order `x, y, z, r, g, b, a`. After looking through similar questions on this topic, I'm still not seeing what I'm missing and/or not doing right, because when I render it with these simple lines:

```
glBindVertexArray(vao);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, verts_amt, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, NULL);
```

it renders just a competey white square. Keep in mind I'm not changing anything else about my rendering loop except of course getting rid of the `Vertex3f`, `glBegin/glEnd`, and `Color4f` calls. I should also mention that I'm not using a shader program, I'm not entirely sure if that changes anything drastically here. Any help on this would be much appreciated!

Comment: Doing things the GL3+ way requires shaders

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I should also mention that I'm not using a shader program.

You cannot use `glVertexAttribPointer` *without* a shader. These functions cannot interface with the OpenGL fixed function pipeline (FFP).

If you want to use the FFP and still use buffer objects, then you should use the appropriate functions. `glVertexPointer` (no "Attrib") and `glColorPointer` are the array equivalents to `glVertex` and `glColor`. These work with VAOs just fine.

So the only thing you need to change is your two `glVertexAttribPointer` calls to be `glVertexPointer` and `glColorPointer` (and of course adjusting the parameters accordingly).

Comment: worked very nicely! It's also good to know about the glVertexAttribPointer being used specifically for shaders, I must've missed that when reading up on the subject